# EF Core Including multiple levels issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

With **EF 6**, I was querying like this and it was working nice.

```
IQueryable<Student> query = _testHelper.buildQuerty(id, userId)
        .Include(x => x.Class)
        .Include(x => x.Subjects)
        .Include(x => x.Subjects.Select(y => y.Category));
```

**Problem:**
The same does not work in **EF Core 2.0**.

**Error**

> System.ArgumentException occurred   HResult=0x80070057   Message=The
>   property expression 'Subjects => {from Subjects y in Subjects select
>   [y].Category}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property
>   access:  't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including
>   related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Opened up link, and refactored like this but it still not working and gives same error.

```
List<Student> query = _testHelper.buildQuerty(id, userId)
        .Include(x => x.Class)
        .Include(x => x.Subjects)
        .ThenInclude(Subjects => Subjects.Select(y => y.Category)).tolist();
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the last chain of `ThenInclude` wrongly. You should use it like the code below.

```
List<Student> query = _testHelper.buildQuerty(id, userId)
        .Include(x => x.Class)
        .Include(x => x.Subjects)
        .ThenInclude(subject => subject.Category);
```

With this `ThenInclude` extension method, you're dealing with an instance of `Subject` because of the last of use of Include which deal with a collection of that type.

Comment: Thanks, i knew this way but was lazy to test. You know the weird thing is Category doesn't show up when you write dot after Subject and instead it shows all collection related things.. thats why i went with other way which was not working. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @simbada I experimented that buggy intellisense behavior on Visual Studio too while doing `ThenInclude`.

Comment: That's because both overloads are Expressions and Intellisense doesn't know which one to pick and always chooses the collection (previously selected navigation property) over the entity